# Heroku and Gitlab private repositories via composer

Tags: git, heroku, composer-php, gitlab

I have a PHP project which uses Composer to handle and download dependencies. Some of those dependencies are on a private Gitlab CE box.

The goal is to deploy to Heroku.

How can I make sure Heroku can access those private repositories?

I suppose there are a few options:

1. Create a deploy key, this seems unsupported by Heroku. I can't seem to find a way of creating an SSH key for Heroku
2. Use an OAuth key, how would I use this in Heroku?

Documentation that seems similar mostly focus on Github integration, such as setting a `COMPOSER_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN` config. Changing this to `GITLAB` won't work.